# How to keep CheckBox checked state in DataList after postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, datalist, autopostback

I'm creating a really simple "tag cloud" function for a project database. I want the user to be able to check various tags and, then, with an autopostback on the checked box(es), display the associated projects that have those tags.

It works, but the checkboxes are resetting after postback. I want the checkboxes to remain checked (or unchecked, as the case may be) so the user can select multiple tags.

I've searched and seen that some say to put the databinding event within an if(!isPostBack). I've tried that, but it doesn't seem to matter.

aspx code:

```
<asp:DataList ID="TagDataList" runat="server" OnDataBinding="databindthesucker" DataKeyField="TagName">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox AutoPostBack="true" ID="TagCheckbox" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval ("dZTagName") %>' />
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="TagNameHidden" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval ("dZTagName") %>'/><br />
                </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:DataList>

<asp:DataList ID="ProjectDataList" runat="server" DataKeyField="projectID">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="ProjectLink" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# "/Project/Default.aspx?PID=" + Eval ("projectID") %>' Text='<%# Eval ("projectID") + ": " + Eval ("projectName") %>'> </asp:HyperLink><br />

                </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:DataList>
```

and then the cs...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        displaytags(sender, e);
     }

    protected void displaytags(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var qrygettags = (from t in db.TagTables
                         select new { t.TagName }).Distinct().ToList();

        TagDataList.DataSource = qrygettags;
        TagDataList.DataBind();
        CheckBox TagCheckbox = (CheckBox)TagDataList.Items[0].FindControl("TagCheckbox");

    }




    protected void databindthesucker(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            foreach (DataListItem item in TagDataList.Items)
            {
                if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
                {
                    CheckBox TagCheckbox = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("TagCheckbox");
                    HiddenField TagNameHidden = (HiddenField)item.FindControl("TagNameHidden");
                    string Tagstring = TagNameHidden.Value.ToString();

                    if (TagCheckbox.Checked)
                    {
                        var qrygetprojects = (from p in db.projects
                                              join pt in db.TagTables on p.projectID equals pt.projectID
                                              where pt.TagName == Tagstring
                                              select new
                                              {
                                                  pt.projectID,
                                                  p.projectName
                                              }).ToList();

                        ProjectDataList.DataSource = qrygetprojects;
                        ProjectDataList.DataBind();

                    }

                }
            }

    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you put everything in your pageload that concerns displaytags and datasources in the if (!IsPostBack)? Just confusing because you say "It works, but the checkboxes are resetting after postback". But if "it works" then that would mean the checkbox has the correct value on postback.

Comment: Sorry, I'll clarify. When I say "it works" what I mean is that when I check a box, it does a postback, and I DO get a list of the projects associated with that tag. But I want the option to check more boxes, so I can select multiple tags. I'd like it to postback each time, and remember the boxes that are checked, so I can further filter my search with more tags. (Hopefully that all makes sense.)

Comment: I think I get it. But why not just select all the boxes you want check and then do one postback?

Comment: I might wind up doing it that way, but I like the idea of "filtering on the fly"... filtering the list with each selection. Seems like I should be able to make it work! But if not, I'll just add a submit, and let it go at that.

Comment: Filtering on the fly is good, but if you want to select multiple filters, then only one postback would be easier & more efficient. On your postback, just make sure you aren't rebinding and have viewstate enabled. But since you said the checkbox value is correct on postback it should be checked as expected when the page loads. Ensure you aren't later clearing the checkbox value before the page renders.

Comment: Thanks. "More efficient" meaning on the database side? Yeah, maybe, but it's a small user group. I envision having quite a few tags in there, and then where do I put the submit? At the bottom? That would make folks frustrated. In any case, I still need to figure out the query when more than one box is checked! (As in, projects with ALL of these tags, or ANY of these tags!)

Comment: Well if you want to make it slick, use jQuery and AJAX :) Sorry I couldn't help with the initial issue. It sounds like it should be working correctly if you get the checked value on postback.